# Inserted records missing

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, insert, record

I use sql server express as my backend and insert records through C#, in ASP Net. In the table . i find only few records are not getting saved while other records get saved in the same table. say my auto identity column looks as 1,2,3,5,8,9,10,13 etc. I have given the identity seed correctly. also application does not throw out any errors.

Please note i m not using any table locks while inserting the records.
Is it required to use a table lock or what could be the issue

any insight in this regard is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: We'll need to see your C# and SQL code to be able to help you.

Comment: Whatever the reason, I would _strongly_ recommend that you not expect your identity values to be consecutive.  you're going to waste time trying to fix identities and risk breaking integrity somewhere.  If you need a consecutive number to order items, use a second column that is either seeded from a table or auto-generated by finding the `MAX+1` value (locking during updates to avoid collisions of course).

Answer (score 1):

Records in a table are not guaranteed to be in order.  Try running the query:

```
select *
from t
order by <auto-identity column>
```

Also, deleting records will create holes in the primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem (actually it's not a problem) doesn't related to locks.

The most possible reason for it can be deleting of records. When a record is deleted the gap in the identity is not filled when a new record is added.

Also, it is possible that query, adding records into the table, uses [IDENTITY_INSERT ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms188059%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx), which allows to insert values into an identity column.

Also, query results are not sorted by identity column unless it's specified in `ORDER BY` clause.

Anyway, if you think that something going wrong, you can run trace in `SQL Server Profiler` and see what is going on the server.